# Why is the Knife Tool not snapping to specific verticies?

Tags: vertices, snapping, knife-tool

I wanted to make arches for a car. I'm trying to cut the mesh verticaly (like on the second photo), but the knife doesn't snap to the verticles on the arches. Although, it does snap to verticles on the edges of the car. How can I snap the knife to the verticles? Thank you.
[image: The Knife Tool snapping to one veriticle and not snapping to another.]

[image: I'm trying to cut this mesh, but knife is not snapping to that verticle.]

Answer (score 1):

Is the curved edge part of the face? I do not think so, since the last vertex has no connection and an edge cannot simply stop in the middle of a face. So when you try to cut the face, the *Knife* tool only snaps to vertices that a part of a face which can be cut.

You have *Snapping* enabled (the magnet symbol), however the *Knife* tool does not use this. *Snapping* only works for transformations like moving, rotating or scaling.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definetly try that.

Comment: @Mark Try what? I just explained why it is not snapping to the vertex 